# Compare the contents of two LDAP servers

Tags: linux, ldap, redhat, openldap

I have inherited two LDAP servers that seem to contain the same information.  My goal is to determine if that is the case or not.  I am able to use slapcat to output an ldif of both servers however I am unable to use diff to compare these files directly because the items are slapcat'd in a different order.

Can these files be reordered so a comparison is possible?

I am unable to use ldapsearch for this because the server limits searches to 500 records and I have over 30,000 records.

Comment: There is LDIFF (https://fruit.je/ldiff). Might try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenDJ has a tool to compare 2 LDIF files: ldif-diff. 
It's slow and requires some memory but we've tested it with files containing hundreds of thousands of entries.

Comment: That tool will work for me!  At first I was getting an out of memory error when using ldif-diff but I manually specified a 8GB heap size and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

[ldapsearch](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ldapsearch) supports the simple paged results control to overcome the (default=500) sizelimit.  There's still a chance you'll hit a [limit](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/limits.html), but you can easily remedy that in the slapd configuration file.

Comment: Using paging appears to not allow a single search to exceed the server limit.  Internet searches support this observation.